# Resharper adds dependency as Reference but not PackageReference in .NET Core projects

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, resharper

Did you faced with the next problem: when i adding a dependency in .NET Core project with Resharper 2018.1 (VS 2017), it adding new dependency (for example) as

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor">
  <HintPath>C:\Users\Fred\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor\2.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

but i need to add it as next (in new format):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="2.0.3" />
```

Сan you advise the solution?

Comment: Do you know for sure this is a ReSharper issue? It doesn't seem related to ReSharper at first glance. How are you adding the dependency?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, when ReSharper suggests to reference a library that is already referenced by another project, it doesn't create a NuGet reference (like it would with the old-style packages.config)